# Should I use separate models for domain and EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Scenario:  I am writing a program that handles report generation.

I have the report stored in a database, mapped to an EF model.  There are some non-database fields (i.e. some fields are auto-calculated based on other fields that ARE in the db).  Would it make sense to have one class that solely maps to the DB, and another class that takes that information and additionally has the other calculating fields?

i.e. a sample class to interact with the codefirst database would be

```
public class Report{
    public int CategoryOneSeverity {get; set;}
    public int CategoryTwoSeverity {get;set;}
    public string Title {get;set;}
}
```

Would it make sense to make another class, like:

```
public class ReportModel{
    public int CategoryOneSeverity;
    public int CategoryTwoSeverity;
    public string Title;

    public int RiskRating{
        get{ return CategoryOneSeverity + CategoryTwoSeverity; }
    }
}
```

Or should the RiskRating property be in the EF model.

Comment: I agree with the accepted answer that you should have separate classes - one to model the data store and one to model your business domain. However, your second class violates a number of good design axioms, the most obvious of which is that fields should not be publicly exposed.

Comment: I really don't like putting in private members and then using a property to get it.  doesn't a field make more sense, especially for areas which are expected to change? i.e. the user can change the title at any moment.

Comment: No, actually, it does not make sense and, as I said, flies in the face of good design. The property allows you to add validation logic, change the backing field representation with a conversion, and ultimately allow you to keep a steady consumer surface area. Let our good friend Jon Skeet say it better: http://www.csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter8/PropertiesMatter.aspx

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, I absolutely believe you should have different classes to model your domain than your DB.  Unless your application is extremely trivial, if you try to map your domain objects directly, you invariably have to change them to match what you need your data structure to be, and possibly expose things you don't want to expose.  Think of it as a violation of the Single Responsibility principle; your class has two reasons to change if you make it your domain object and map it directly.  One is in response to changing business requirements, the other is in response to changing data storage schema.

Comment: " your class has two reasons to change if you make it your domain object and map it directly. One is in response to changing business requirements, the other is in response to changing data storage schema." - That helped me visualize it perfectly.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

> "Would it make sense to have one class that solely maps to the DB, and
>   another class that takes that information and additionally has the
>   other calculating fields?"

Most likely yes.  Usually I would create a new class suffixed with "ViewModel" such as HumanResourcesReportViewModel if my entity class was HumanResourcesReport.

There's lots of variations on how to use ViewModels, and we could get into a pedantic debate about terminology, but conceptually, take your entity and create a new class with that data plus whatever additional information you need to process the report.  In this case the report generation is in a way the View of the MVC model, so I don't think it's offensive to call the class holding the data a ViewModel.

Comment: I think you're talking about the other end of the architecture; i.e. the UI.  ViewModels are used in the UI; that's why they're called `View` models.

Comment: @Robert The report generation is at the View end.  You get the data from the database, shape it into a ViewModel, then generate a report which is your presentation of the data.  Whether it is generated through a report engine or a html engine, it is a view.  You can call it whatever you are comfortable with, but conceptually it is the same thing.  You need some extra data that isn't part of the entity.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean.  Calculating RiskRating is a *display* function.

Answer (score 4):

Are you using Code First or DB First?

You can have auto calculated fields in your model, which are not mapped to fields in the database.

It also depends on your architecture. If you're using DB first, refreshing your EF model would update your EF classes, losing your mapped fields. In the DB-First scenario, an alternative would be to use the EF model class as your base class and inherit from it for your report class.

```
public class ReportModel
{
    public int CategoryOneSeverity;
    public int CategoryTwoSeverity;
    public string Title;
}   

public class ReportClass : ReportModel
{
    public int RiskRating
    { 
        get { return CategoryOneSeverity + CategoryTwoSeverity; }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works out pretty poorly in all but the most trivial of applications.

Comment: +1 You can also add properties directly to your ReportModel class and tag them with the `[NotMapped]` attribute.  Saves you an extra class, but on the other hand it clutters your entity class with properties you may not use often.  So it is a bit of a judgement call on which way you go.

Comment: Andy: There was not a lot of information to go on and was intended to show what could be achieved, with the information provided, rather than a fully working solution.

Comment: @KarlGjertsen Understood, but I think the most likely assumption is that the application will be non-trivial, and based on that assumption we should provide the best answer.